# Does Yarn use .yarn/releases/yarn by default?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-v2

`yarn set version latest` downloads a Yarn release to `<projectRoot>/.yarn/releases/yarn-<version>.cjs`.

When `yarn` is ran in the project's root, does Yarn automatically use the version included in the aforementioned folder, or does it use the global version?

If it doesn't use it automatically, I assume the engineer working with the project is supposed to just `node path-to-release` it?

Answer (score 0):

It uses the version at `<projectRoot>/.yarn/releases/yarn-<version>.cjs` because `yarn set version latest` adds to `.yarnrc` an entry like this `yarn-path ".yarn/releases/yarn-<latest-version>.cjs"`.

> yarn-path "./bin/yarn"
>
> Instructs yarn to defer to another Yarn binary for execution.

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/yarnrc#toc-yarn-path